# Jquery only appends canvas to one of the selected elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have severals `span` in my html layout, to each i would like to append a `canvas`-element with jquery. I tried this with a `for-each`-loop:

```
$.each($('span'), function(index,element){
        element.append('<canvas width="' + element.width + '" height="' + element.heigth + '"></canvas>');
        var context = $(element).find('canvas').first().getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage($('img').first(), 0,0);
    });
```

But somehow a canvas is only appended to the first span in the layout! Why? Thanks!

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/aXNYx/

Comment: Your code is really broken, you even spelled height wrong. The fiddle is also not properly setup. Please fix your question and look at the error messages in your console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving this fiddle a try.

http://jsfiddle.net/p55T2/1/

- width and height are functions to be called.
- you misspelled height as heigth
- `first()` doesn't appear to be working, you might want to research why.